# What part of the electron mass is due to Yukawa coupling?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, higgs

Sorry if this question is wrong - then please correct it.

A particle mass can be due to a Dirac mass term or due to a Yukawa mass term. In the standard model, which percentage of the electron mass is due to which term?

**Added after the comments came in:**

The comments explain that Yukawa coupling generate Dirac terms. So allow me to ask the question in this way.

Could there be an intrinsic Dirac mass **and** a Yukawa-induced mass? Or, again differently: Does really **all** mass derive from Yukawa coupling or could it be that only a part of the mass comes from coupling to the Higgs?

I remember that I read (serious) papers explaining that both an intrinsic and a Yukawa aspect of the mass could exist. But I just cannot remember where...

Comment: For the electron, all of it. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43794/271654

Comment: The Yukawa mass term *is* a Dirac mass term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's consider this in the context of a very simple toy model, which however is not the Standard Model. In particular, we will just imagine one fermion and one scalar field with a Yukawa coupling
\begin{equation}
S = \int {\rm d}^4 x \left( - \frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi)^2 -V(\phi )+ i\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m \bar\psi \psi - g \bar\psi \phi \psi \right)
\end{equation}
Now if the scalar field has a VEV $\bar\Phi$, so $\phi = \bar\Phi+\varphi$, then the fermions have a physical mass
\begin{equation}
m_{\rm phys} \equiv m + g \bar{\Phi}
\end{equation}
This physical mass is the quantity that is actually observed, since it corresponds to a pole in the fermion propagator.

Meanwhile, three point scattering between the scalar particles $\varphi$ and the fermions will lead to a three point interaction, with a scattering amplitude
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}_{\bar\psi \varphi \psi} \propto i g + ...
\end{equation}
where the $...$ refers to higher order corrections, and I've been lazy with delta functions and spin traces. Therefore, the Yukawa couplings can be determined via scattering processes with the Higgs.

Since the VEV is a constant, if the Dirac mass is zero, this implies that there is a relationship between the scattering amplitudes between fermions and the Higgs, and the fermion masses. In particular, with multiple generations of fermions, the ratio of top-quark-higgs scattering amplitudes to bottom-quark-higgs scattering amplitudes, should be related to the ratio of the top and bottom quark physical masses. If each fermion had its own Dirac mass unrelated to the Yukawa couplings, this would break the relationship between the scattering amplitudes and physical masses.

That's how things work in the toy model. However, in the Standard Model, there is an extra wrinkle. In particular, there the weak interactions are a *chiral* gauge symmetry $SU(2)_L$ which only acts on *left-handed* fermions. A Dirac mass term couples left and right handed fermions, and so necessarily break the chiral gauge symmetry. Therefore in the Standard Model, the Dirac mass *must* be exactly zero. Of course, that doesn't stop people from checking if the Yukawa couplings are consistent with the masses, since of course finding any violation of predictions from the Standard Model would be very exciting and important.

To summarize, our current state of knowledge is that the Dirac masses must be exactly zero, to preserve the chiral gauge invariance. However, there are experimental tests that can be done to check this. Measuring the interaction strengths between particles and the Higgs is one of the goals of the proposed next generation colliders, in part for this reason.

Comment: This is wonderfully explained.

Comment: Does this mean that the lack of Dirac mass is related to the observation that parity violation is  maximal/complete?

Comment: @Christian These things are related: the weak interactions break parity since the weak interactions are a chiral gauge theory. And the Dirac mass term is forbidden by the chiral gauge symmetry. But the gauge symmetry is a stronger requirement than parity, if the issue was "just" that the weak interactions had to violate parity, you could have parity-violating interactions and sill have a Dirac mass term.

Comment: I understand that parity violation would be possible with a Dirac (or better, a non-Yukawa) mass. Sorry to ask again: Is then *maximal* parity violation equivalent zero Dirac mass in your example? Or would *maximal* parity violation be possible also with a non-zero Dirac mass? And finally: where can I read more about this?

Comment: @Christian I don't know what you mean by *maximal* parity violation. Symmetries are broken or not, there is not a sliding scale of a symmetry being slightly to maximally broken. You can have approximate symmetries, which means pretending you have a symmetry that is not really there gives approximately correct results. Parity is an approximate symmetry because it holds if you ignore weak interactions. Anyway, the best thing is probably to read a text on particle physics, like Griffiths' book, or the discussion after Eq 14.34 here: https://cds.cern.ch/record/292286/files/B00008237.pdf

Comment: Thank you. If I google "maximal parity violation" or "violates parity maximally" I get back your SU(2)_L property; so I guess it is an older way to say the same thing.